# How to make a mod to a binary executable?

Tags: binaryfiles

I have seen people making mods to executable to add extra self-used functionalities, I puzzled by the fact that they can modify a software without source code. Can you tell me how is that possible? Well, I know there are tools like SoftICE, OllyDbg or IDA, but I think those tools can only let you modified a few fields or just change some critical jump point, how can they add extra dlls which impletment new functions to the original executable? I am interesting in the detail process , can anyone give me some instruction?

Comment: This isn't exactly an easy task.  You basically have to inject your own code in between two parts of existing code.  Your code then does its own thing then forwards to where the original code was calling.  Unless you're doing this just out of curiosity and you're willing to waste a ton of time, I wouldn't go down this path.

Comment: It's out of curiosity~ That mean I basically have to loop at the disambled code of the executable and try to figure out what they do? Then it seems what this guy have done is awesome:http://utorrentleechermodserenity.wordpress.com/  Please know that I cited Owyn doesn't make supporter of his mod

Comment: You have two options: Either disassemble it into assembly, try to inject a jmp to one of your own functions whereever you need to, then at the end of that function jmp to the original jmp, or you can try to go at it programmatically.  That would require using some very low level APIs to find addresses of certain symbols and then manipulating the code there (basically the same thing).  It's been a very long time since I've done anything like this (and I was terrible at it :p), so I can't help you much with the specifics.

Comment: Thank you @Corbin . Can you recommend some websites that you once learn the techniques?